# Add images to pdf file using prawn on Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, pdf, prawn

I've got pdf file and I want to add an image on it. There are two pages in my pdf file and I want to add image on every page.

```
Prawn::Document.generate("img/full_template.pdf", :template => "img/template.pdf") do |pdf|
  avatar = "img/crop_after.png"
  pdf.image avatar, :at => [100,10], :scale => 0.4
  pdf.image avatar, :at => [300,30], :scale => 0.4
end
```

When I run this code I got four avatar images on first pdf page (two in full size and two scaled and in position I want). 
Can anyone tell me, how can I add first image to the first pdf page and second image to second pdf page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `start_new_page` between the images.

That way your second image will be placed on a new page.

EDIT: If your template already has multiple pages you can use `go_to_page` to navigate between the pages

http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Document.html#method-i-go_to_page

Comment: Yes, second image on new blank page but I want it on the second page of editing pdf file. If I add start_new_page between the images I've got first page with fullsized avatar and scaled avatar, second page with scaled avatar and third page with data, that was previously on second page of my pdf file

Comment: Ok, so your template already has data on it and start_new_page would insert a new page between the first and second page of the template? Try go_to_page (see edited answer)

Comment: Thank you. I know this function, but it didn't help. It's real magic, I found, that the problem not in my code but in template pdf. In it's first page. I don't know why, but only on first page of this pdf I have this problem. I tried 3 more pdf files, and images added perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: well, one possible solution would be to create the pdf using prawn from scratch (without anything in the template) - more work but that would probably solve the issue